# How to include lines in an equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmark

I am a newbie to latex and I am trying to compile notes. I came across an equation and I am wondering how it was produced. I haven't tried any method as I have no clue. Please help particularly with how to draw these lines.

[image: Virtual work equation].

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See `tikzmark` package or `tikzmark` library of Ti*k*Z.

Comment: [A solution I wrote a few weeks ago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583193/labeling-two-different-parts-of-one-equation-with-two-arrows-with-different-star/583209#583209) that may help you.

Comment: Will it be possible to update the solution to include label and equation number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

    \[ 
    \tikzmarknode{N1}{1}\cdot
    \tikzmarknode{N2}{\Delta}=\Sigma
    \tikzmarknode{N3}{\vphantom{L}u}\cdot
    \tikzmarknode{N4}{dL}
    \]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,shorten <=2pt]
        \draw (N1) |-++ (3,.5) node[right] {virtual loadings};
        \draw (N3) --++ (0,.5);
        
        \draw (N2) |-++ (3,-.5) node[right] {real displacements};
        \draw (N4) --++ (0,-.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: simple tikzmark]

Note that `\vphantom{L}` into `node` `N3` is only here to avoid height disrupcy on your equation which would lead to mandatory manual setting for the drawing lines afterwards. With it, you don't have to think about it in the `tikzpicture` part.

#### EDIT

A more logical solution is to declare nodes for the legends and draw the second paths to the nodes. It avoids any `\vphantom` into the equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

    \[ 
    \tikzmarknode{N1}{1}\cdot
    \tikzmarknode{N2}{\Delta}=\Sigma
    \tikzmarknode{N3}{u}\cdot
    \tikzmarknode{N4}{dL}
    \]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,shorten <=2pt]
    
        \draw (N1) |-++ (3,.5) node[right] (V) {virtual loadings};
        \draw (N3) |- (V);
        
        \draw (N2) |-++ (3,-.5) node[right] (R) {real displacements};
        \draw (N4) |- (R);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: v2]

Comment: I just edited my post to add a second version to avoid `\vphantom` into the equation.

Comment: Thanks a million times

Comment: Hi, @SebGlav. I'd like to do something similar, although slightly different and I hope I can dot it learning from your code. Could you add a brief explanation about the functions of each part of your code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Alice I strongly recommend to read the [tikzmark package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) which is very self explanatory. Then, feel free to ask another question on TeX-SE, adding the `tikz` and `tikzmark` tags. You sure will get answers. Briefly, `\tikzmarknode` adds a node containing the text, which node you can use later to draw from, or whatever you want  to do with it. Here I created nodes for `1`, `Delta`, `u` and `dL` and drew lines from them.

Comment: Thank you so much. Eventually, I figured it out.