# How to code arrows that go from one line to another

Tags: diagrams

I'm trying to implement the next chain of events:

[image]

But I don't know how to. I would appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance!

Edit: After getting a grasp of how this forum work I'll try to narrow the problem. How can I make an arrow that goes from one line to another and also "space" the different lines so that they start at different points? Would this imply some kind of "anchor", for the arrows, that I can place at any point? I'm new to LateX so any kind of further literature is appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Though asking a question like 'do it for me' is not appreciated, your question is interesting and should lead in multiple answers with different visions of the solution.

Comment: Sorry for that. I was by no mean trying to get the work done by someone else. I was more hoping for a starting point like some kind of package. I'll try to avoid this kind of question in the future, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution in Ti*k*Z, using `tikzmark` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,every node/.style={outer sep=2pt},->]
        \node {$\Xi^{*-} \rightarrow \tikzmarknode{L1-1}{K}^- + \tikzmarknode{L1-2}\Sigma^0$};
        
        \draw (L1-1) |-++ (.5,-1.5) node[right] {$\tikzmarknode{L4-1}{\pi}^- + \tikzmarknode{L4-2}{\pi}^0$};

        \draw (L1-2) |-++ (.2,-.5) node[right] {$\tikzmarknode{L2-1}{\Lambda}^0 + \gamma$};
        
        \draw (L2-1) |-++ (.2,-.5) node[right] {$p+\mathrm{e}^-+\bar{\nu}_{\mathrm{e}}$};
        
        \draw (L4-1) |-++ (.2,-1) node[right] {$\tikzmarknode{L6-1}{\mu}+ \bar{\nu}_\mu$};
        \draw (L4-2) |-++ (.2,-.5) node[right] {$\gamma + \gamma$};
        
        \draw (L6-1) |-++ (.2,-.5) node[right] {$\mathrm{e}^- + \bar{\nu}_{\mathrm{e}} + \nu_\mu$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Each line is numbered from L1 to L6 and nodes are tikzmarked from left to right, i.e. `(L1-1)`, `(L1-2)`, etc.
[image: tikzmark in node]

Comment: Thank you Sleb! I didn't know TikZ existed. What do you recommend for me to learn to use this library?

Comment: You're very welcome. If you are to make this kind of graphic a lot, you may consider to learn a bit how to use it. It's pretty straightforward: where you want to draw a further arrow (or any other drawing) you place a `tikzmark` if you don't have anything to write in, or a `tikzmarknode` if you want to write something iside. Then, because you named those nodes, you can use them later to draw in Ti*k*Z. Just take some time to figure how I wrote this example and if you want to know more, you can search for other examples in TeX-SE.

Comment: See for example [How to add lines in an equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586711/how-to-include-lines-in-an-equation/586743#586743).

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: @H.B Don't hesitate to accept the answer that suits you the most, so that future visitors know it's a closed question.