# Making a decay diagram with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-node

I am trying to get a diagram of the decay shown in the picture. Sadly I have little to no knowledge concerning tikz and the results look horrible. Since I do not have enough time to really learn how to use tikz, I am reaching out to you. I only need to know how to create the nodes and connect the arrows properly. Till now my nodes have a rectangle around them and the K+ and Lambda are shifted, if they are in different nodes. Also I cannot connect the nodes properly (the arrow should begin right below the Lambda and go to the Sigma). If anyone can help, it would be very kind of you.
Thanks, Emil

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node[draw] (a) {\KPlus}; 
\node[draw,right of=a] (k) {\Lam}; 
\node[draw,below right of=k] (b) {\SigmaO}; 
\node[draw,right of=b] (c) {\PiO}; 
\draw[vecArrow] (k) |- (b); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: The result I plan to get]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Regardless that result of your effort looks horrible (as you say), show us what you try so far.

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw] (a) {\KPlus};
  \node[draw,right of=a] (k) {\Lam}; 
  \node[draw,below right of=k] (b) {\SigmaO};
  \node[draw,right of=b] (c) {\PiO};

  \draw[vecArrow] (k) |- (b);

\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: The \Lam etc are predefined and could be replaced by \Lambda (1520) etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to code arrows that go from one line to another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587268/how-to-code-arrows-that-go-from-one-line-to-another)

Comment: You may want to edit your question and add the code that you posted as comment.

Comment: Thank you all, the answer of SebGlav was exactly what I was searching for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possibility using `tikz` and the `matrix` library. You can adjust `row sep` and `column sep` however you like. Additional spacing adjustments can be made using `&[<length>]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix(decay)[matrix of math nodes, nodes={anchor=base}, row sep=1ex]{
K^+\Lambda(1520)\\
 &[-6mm] \Sigma^0\pi^0\\
 & & \gamma\gamma\\
 & & \gamma\Lambda &[3mm] p\pi^-\\
 & & & \pi^0n\\
 & pK^-\\
 & \Sigma^{\pm}\pi^{\mp}\\
};
\draw[-stealth](decay-1-1)|-(decay-2-2);
\draw[-stealth]([xshift=-1mm]decay-1-1.south)|-(decay-6-2);
\draw[-stealth]([xshift=-2mm]decay-1-1.south)|-(decay-7-2);
\draw[-stealth]([xshift=1mm]decay-2-2.south)|-(decay-3-3);
\draw[-stealth]([xshift=-2.5mm]decay-2-2.south)|-(decay-4-3);
\draw[-stealth](decay-4-3)--(decay-4-4);
\draw[-stealth](decay-4-3)|-(decay-5-4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```